# Show $P(S_{2n}=x|S_0=x) \ge \frac{1}{N}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $X_n$ be an aperiodic, discrete-time Markov chain so $S=\{1,...,N\}$ whose transition probability is symmetric. How can I show that for all $x \in S$ and all integers $n$, $P(S_{2n}=x|S_0=x) \ge \frac{1}{N}$. And would this hold in $2n$ is replaced with $2n+1$?

I'm really stuck and have no idea how to do this practice problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: is it S2N? S2n?

Comment: Do you mean 'not greater than' by writing '>\'?

Comment: Firstly its S2n and secondly, i meant greater than and equal to.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ denote the transition matrix of the Markov chain, then $p$ is symmetric hence $p^n(x,y)=p^n(y,x)$ for every $x$ and $y$ in $S$ and, for every $x$ in $S$,
$$
|S|\cdot p^{2n}(x,x)=|S|\cdot\sum_{y\in S}p^n(x,y)p^n(y,x)=\sum_{y\in S}1\cdot\sum_{y\in S}(p^n(x,y))^2.
$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, the RHS is at least
$$
\left(\sum_{y\in S}p(x,y)\right)^2=1.$$

> And would this hold in $2n$ is replaced with $2n+1$?

No, as shown by chains of period $2$ in a neighborhood of radius $n+1$ around $x$.